# Disable an inputField (when a sObject record is readonly in the user assigned Profile)

Tags: apex, visualforce, apexinputfield, read-only

I want to make an inputField disabled when a sObject record is read-only for a user. Tried using Disabled property but it doesn't support for inputField.

I have two doubts:-
1. How to check if the record is Read-Only in the controller for users?
2. How can I disable the inputField according to the above criteria since the Disabled property doesn't support for inputField ?

Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The `<apex:inputField>` tag should do this for you automatically. That said, here is a good article from Salesforce with example code that looks at the different techniques that force.com applications can use to enforce a customer's security settings: [Enforcing CRUD and FLS](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Enforcing_CRUD_and_FLS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get this sorted without using Apex and only using Visualforce using the following method checking if the record is Updateable and rendering the values depending on the criteria.

{!$ObjectType.objectname.fields.fieldname.Updateable}

Answer (score 3):

You can check record access using the UserRecordAccess object like so:

```
SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId = [single ID] AND RecordId = [single ID]
```

Documentation here: https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm

I would create a boolean in your controller to store the result, and then toggle the components in your VF like so:

```
<apex:outputField value="{!myRecord.myField}" rendered="{!RECORD_IS_READONLY}"/>
<apex:inputField value="{!myRecord.myField}" rendered="{!Not(RECORD_IS_READONLY)}"/>
```

You could do some clever stuff in Apex with dynamic VisualForce but that would be overkill for this scenario I think.

Comment: Thanks! This helps. I also found another way doing it only using Visualforce and rendering $ObjectType method checking if the record is updateable.